# split into arrays from a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am using Java 1.4 for an old project.

I have a **string array**

```
       String a[0]={"200,300"}
       String a[1]={"700,500"}
       String a[2]={"900,400"}
```

as so on,

for this I need to create **2 string array** to get the first value in a string array and second value in different string array.

ex:

```
String a[0]="200"
String a[1]="700"
String a[2]="900"

String b[0]="300"
String b[1]="500"
String b[2]="400"
```

I am not getting how can I do this.

Comment: what have u tried to solve it?

Comment: Hint : Assign array's 0th index data to a array and 1st index data to b. Also reconsider the array declaration for the string array you made...

Comment: I had a logic like I can create two string array where in first string array I can eliminate the first value where as in second one I will eliminate the value after ',' .but that code is not working properly.

Comment: @upadhyaykc take a look at my answer below.

Comment: @Prasad : The code is giving junk value for 2nd record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, this provides you the correct solution,

```
int n = 3; //This can change as your array size is not known
String a[] = new String [n];
   a[0]="200,300";
   a[1]="700,500";
   a[2]="900,400"; //And So on


String[] b1 = new String [n];
String[] b2 = new String [n];

for(int i = 0; i<n ; i++)
{
   String [] numbers= a[i].split(",");
   b1[i] = numbers[0];
   b2[i] = numbers[1];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the length of the string array is known,

```
String[] newString = new String [6];
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<3 ; i++){
   newString[i] = a[i];
   count++;
}
for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
   newString[count] = b[j];
   count++;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Previously i got your question wrong. The following solution will help you. to divide `a` into 2 string arrays.

```
    String a[] = new String [3];
       a[0]={"200,300"};
       a[1]={"700,500"};
       a[2]={"900,400"};

    String[] newStr1 = new String [a.length];
    String[] newStr2 = new String [a.length];

    for(int i = 0; i<3 ; i++){
       String [] x= a[i].split(",");
       newStr1[i] = x[0];
       newStr2[i] = x[1];

    }
```

Comment: `{200,300}` on splitting this string you get **{200** in `x[0]` to avoid 1st **{** i used `substring()`

Comment: @dbw: why have you deleted your post that gave me exact result. :) :)

Comment: @upadhyaykc I deleted because I thought the array elements are stored with brackets as told by Prasad

Comment: @upadhyaykc why you've removed tick from the answer BTW?

Comment: @prasad: Sorry Prasad,Because before editing it was giving junk value for  2nd record which I already mention in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

First you cant defined String array as `string a[1]={700,500}`. It is wrong way.

And second, Here is what you want :

```
a[0]=new String[]{"200","300"};
a[1]=new String[]{"700","500"};
a[2]=new String[]{"900","400"};

String x[] = new String[a.length];
String y[] = new String[a.length];
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    x[i] = a[i][0];
    y[i] = a[i][1];
}
```

Comment: it is given an error " the type of expression must be an array type but it resolved to string" .   my code is : 'String []strId=null; strId=req.getParameterValues("Id");'

Comment: Define `a` like this : `String a[][] = new String[3][2];`

Comment: since I am storing only one parameter value which is like '200,700' I can not use 2Darray. :(